# Fetch data by a month and day in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table Task with has a createdDate column. I need to get all the tasks which are created in a  particular month and each day should not have more than 4 records. If there are more than 4 records in a particular date then we can get only those first 4 records which are crated first. There is a another column CreatedTime.

```
Task
(
  id
  ,CreatedDate
  ,CreatedTime

)
```

Result should be

```
id      CreatedDate

1       1/1/2013  
2       1/1/2013  
3       1/1/2013  
4       1/1/2013  
5       1/2/2013  
6       1/2/2013  
7       1/2/2013  
8       1/2/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery or Common Table Expression (CTE). The subquery version:

```
SELECT
    * --TODO: Columns
FROM
    (SELECT
        *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CreatedDate ORDER BY CreatedTime) as rn
     FROM
        Task
    ) t
WHERE
    rn between 1 and 4
```

If you had possible ties in your data (two rows with the same `CreatedTime` on the same day) and you needed to take those into explicit consideration, you could swap `ROW_NUMBER` with `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`, as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
; WITH A AS (
SELECT ID, CreatedDate
, convert(VARCHAR(7), CreatedDate, 121) AS YearMonth --will return something like 2012-01 
FROM Task
), 
B AS (
SELECT ID, CreatedDate
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YearMonth ORDER BY CreatedDate, ID) AS RowNum
FROM A)
SELECT ID, CreatedDate
FROM B
WHERE RowNum<=4
ORDER BY ID
```

This works on SQL 2005 and later versions.

1. First in CTE A you find your partitioning column (YearMonth),
2. then in B you assign an RowNum for each record (this can be changed based on your ordering citeria)
3. and then you get the final result.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have done some changes and got the solutions here.

Comment: Yeah, responded this before 10 AM :). Now I see that you wanted the first results for each day. If you convert to Varchar(10) you get a full day (without time) and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you reply. I have done some changes and got the solutions here.

```
; WITH A 
AS 
(
SELECT ID, CreatedDate , DAY(CreatedDate) AS Day 
FROM Task
WHERE CreatedDate BETWEEN '01/01/2013 00:00:00' AND '01/31/2013 23:59:59' 
)
,
B AS 
(
    SELECT 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Day ORDER BY CreatedDate, ID) AS RowNum 
    ,*
    FROM A
)


select 
 DAY(CreatedDate) as Day1
, MONTH(CreatedDate) as Month
, YEAR(dueDate) as Year
, * 
from B 
WHERE RowNum <= 4
order by Year,Month,Day1, CreatedDate
```